# in iOS webRTC peer connection does not allow audio and video on mobile data-connection but works fine on wifi connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, peer-connection

Error shown on debug console :

> block invoke: No valid RTCReporting and the session was started.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please describe your question verbosely to get better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC video and Audio in IOS not working with 3G /4G but works with WIFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057400/webrtc-video-and-audio-in-ios-not-working-with-3g-4g-but-works-with-wifi)