# WebRTC video and Audio in IOS not working with 3G /4G but works with WIFI

Tags: ios, socket.io, webrtc, peer-connection

I am trying to connect WebRTC video and audio in iOS connected by 3g/4g gives error but works fine with WiFi network.

And after the peer connection is found the error appears

> [carc] CAReportingClient.mm:320:-[CAReportingClient sendMessage:category:type:reporters:]_block_invoke: The operation couldn’t be completed. No valid RTCReporting and the session was started

Comment: better if you can provide some relevant code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Call setup failing on 3G/4G but working in a local network is symptomatic of a STUN failure. See if you are supplying at least one valid STUN server to the WebRTC engine in your iOS code.

**Edit:** It's also possible that a peer-to-peer connection cannot be established in your 3G/4G setup. So you also need to make sure you are supplying a valid TURN server as well.

Comment: it works fine when iphones are connected to different far away wifi connecting over the internet but does not work if any of the iphone is connected to 3g 4g  and not over the wifi

Comment: OK, are you also supplying a valid TURN server?

Comment: yes i guess so because applications get each other's peer IPs alongwith port number but don't send audio and video over that

Comment: @jamix I also got the same error message saying "The operation couldn’t be completed. No valid RTCReporting and the session was started", I have used google's stun server "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302" and numb turn server "turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478" with my credentials. I also checked that turn server gives the ICE candidates by the use of (https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/). My both device iPad and iPhone are using same wifi(mac's wifi). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @BilalHassan above error comes if we not exchange the ICE candidate properly, I'm still facing the same error but some times it connects and audio call get established, let me know if you have any better way to exchange the ICE candidate(Trickle ICE do work for me sometimes)

Comment: @MahadevMandale that error is only turn server 
find a working turn server or create your own

Comment: @BilalHassan Is not "turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478" a valid turn server? Is your error resolved after providing valid TURN server?

Comment: @MahadevMandale maybe not 
find out a valid Firewall Traversal TURN Server
and all will be fine...

Comment: @BilalHassan which turn server you have used?